# scalaxb fails when an element and an attribute at the same level having the same name

Tags: scala, sbt, xml-binding, scalaxb, sbt-scalaxb

I am trying to use the [`sbt-scalaxb`](http://scalaxb.org/sbt-scalaxb) to generate bindings for the [`FixRepository.xsd`](https://github.com/FIXTradingCommunity/fix-repository/blob/master/2010_edition/Unified/FixRepository.xsd) and it does not like the SUBJ.

As a last resort, of cause, I can to slightly change the schema, but is there maybe a way to tune the [`sbt-scalaxb`](http://scalaxb.org/sbt-scalaxb) to understand the original file?

The XSD fragment the [`sbt-scalaxb`](http://scalaxb.org/sbt-scalaxb) does not like is:

`xml
    <xs:element name="component">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="messageEntity" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attributeGroup ref="entityAttribGrp"/>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="id_t" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="type" type="ComponentType_t" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="repeating" type="BOOL_t" use="optional"/>
            <xs:attribute name="category" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
            <xs:attribute name="abbrName" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
            <xs:attribute name="notReqXML" type="BOOL_t" use="optional"/>
            <!-- would like to force a description of the component -->
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out myself: `scalaxbAttributePrefix` setting adds a prefix to the attribute properties.

### build.sbt

```
scalaxbAttributePrefix in (Compile, scalaxb) := Some("attr")
```

### Generated FixRepository.scala

```
case class Fix(
    ...,
    components: ...fixrepo.Components,
    ...,
    attributes: Map[String, scalaxb.DataRecord[Any]] = Map()
) {
    ...
    lazy val attrComponents = attributes("@components").as[BOOL_t]
    ...
}
```